# Mutation chain generator

Tags: code-golf, string, sequence

Given a start word and a target word, print the "mutation chain" that starts at the start word and ends at the target word.

You may assume both words are lowercase and only have alphabetic characters.

Define a "mutation" as the removal of an character, the insertion of a character, or the altering of a character.

For example, "hi" can be mutated into:

ahi
ai
bhi
bi
chi
ci
dhi
di
ehi
ei
fhi
fi
ghi
gi
h
ha
hai
hb
hbi
hc
hci
hd
hdi
he
hei
hf
hfi
hg
hgi
hh
hhi
hhi
hi
hi
hia
hib
hic
hid
hie
hif
hig
hih
hii
hii
hij
hik
hil
him
hin
hio
hip
hiq
hir
his
hit
hiu
hiv
hiw
hix
hiy
hiz
hj
hji
hk
hki
hl
hli
hm
hmi
hn
hni
ho
hoi
hp
hpi
hq
hqi
hr
hri
hs
hsi
ht
hti
hu
hui
hv
hvi
hw
hwi
hx
hxi
hy
hyi
hz
hzi
i
ihi
ii
jhi
ji
khi
ki
lhi
li
mhi
mi
nhi
ni
ohi
oi
phi
pi
qhi
qi
rhi
ri
shi
si
thi
ti
uhi
ui
vhi
vi
whi
wi
xhi
xi
yhi
yi
zhi
zi

A mutation chain is a chain of these mutations, such as:

hi -> hei -> heio -> helo -> hello

Your task is to calculate the shortest possible mutation chain that starts from one word and ends in the other. Since there may be multiple such chains, you may print any.

For example, when

```
hi
hello
```

is input, the output may be

```
hi
hei
heio
helo
hello
```

or any valid chain of length 5.

Standard loopholes apply; shortest code wins.
For an arbitrary start word and end word of length less than 30, your program should terminate in less than a minute when run on a standard PC (i.e. Core 2 Duo) and use less than 128 MB of memory.

Comment: Is this sequence also okay? ```hi->he->hel->hell->hello```

Comment: Suggested test case `tt` -> `test` for programs that might replace the second `t` rather than insert between them.